# Is it possible to teleport armor stands above specified items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and I have items randomly appear on the ground. I'm trying to make armor stands teleport to above the items to act a as a beacon. Is there any way to do that? I've tried looking at an items nbt data but nothing work.

Comment: Do you want the armor stands to have stuff on them, or just be blank?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

Repeating command block, always active:

```
execute at @e[type=item] run summon armorstand ~ ~ ~
```

If you want a less laggier version of this, connect this chain command block to your item-summoning command mechanism:
Chain command block, always active:

```
execute at @e[type=item] run summon armorstand ~ ~ ~
```

I hope this helps.